# How do I know the persistent file size for storing changes of a bootable USB stick?

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, persistence

How do I know the persistent file size for storing changes of a bootable USB stick? I need to know: A) the space given to persistent storage B) how much of it is free.

My idea is to copy some of my files into the usb drive until it gets full. I am asking this question in order to know when to stop.

I created it using Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer and following this [instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No one? Please, I need to know this.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and type the following command:

```
df . -h
```

Output can look like:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow                   14G   74M   13G   1% /
```

And in case you like to change the size of the persistent file you can take a look at:

http://ubuntu-usb-large-persistent-storage.blogspot.nl/

Have Fun

Ronald

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that does not solve my question. I tried running the command you told and the output only shows hard drives (not usb flash drives).